# delete a record from the specified table in MySQL with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on a registration form with MySQL and PHP, I have 2 table in MySQL: users and a_codes.
before I defined and insert some username into the a_codes table.
when a user enters a username in the registration form.it's checked with records in the a_codes table, if exist then registration done.
my problem is that I want after the user successfully registered, the mentioned username in the a_codes table must be deleted.
everything in my code below worked fine. the only question is how to delete the used username in the a_codes table?
. I'm new in PHP and thanks for any help.

```
<?php 

require_once 'DbConnect.php';

//an array to display response
$response = array();

if(isset($_GET['apicall'])){

    switch($_GET['apicall']){

        case 'signup':
            //checking the parameters required are available or not 
            if(isTheseParametersAvailable(array('username','email','password','gender'))){

                //getting the values 
                $username = $_POST['username']; 
                $email = $_POST['email']; 
                $password = md5($_POST['password']);
                $gender = $_POST['gender']; 

                //checking if the user is already exist in a_codes table with this username 
                $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT id FROM a_codes WHERE username = ?");
                $stmt->bind_param("s", $username);
                $stmt->execute();
                $stmt->store_result();

                //if the user already exist in the database 
                if($stmt->num_rows > 0){ 
                //if user is already exist creating an insert query 
                    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO users (username, email, password, gender) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
                    $stmt->bind_param("ssss", $username, $email, $password, $gender);

                    //if the user is successfully added to the database 
                    if($stmt->execute()){

                        //fetching the user back 
                        $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT id, id, username, email, gender FROM users WHERE username = ?"); 
                        $stmt->bind_param("s",$username);
                        $stmt->execute();
                        $stmt->bind_result($userid, $id, $username, $email, $gender);
                        $stmt->fetch();

                        $user = array(
                            'id'=>$id, 
                            'username'=>$username, 
                            'email'=>$email,
                            'gender'=>$gender
                        );

                        $stmt->close();

                        //adding the user data in response 
                        $response['error'] = false; 
                        $response['message'] = 'done'; 
                        $response['user'] = $user; 
                    }


                } else {

                    $response['error'] = true;
                    $response['message'] = 'already registered';
                    $stmt->close();
                }

            }else{
                $response['error'] = true; 
                $response['message'] = 'error eccoured'; 
            }

            break;
```

Comment: Have you made any _attempt_ to delete the record? What exactly are you having trouble with?

Comment: An SQL statement saying something like `DELETE FROM a_codes WHERE username=?` may be what you need.

Comment: Welcome. To ask [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), please read [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 and [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)
 **We are very willing to help you fix your code, but we dont write code for you**

Comment: yes. I paste a piece of code like this: DELETE FROM a_codes WHERE username = ?")   but didn't work

Comment: I need a part of PHP codes that delete the username value in the a_codes table. and where I paste it?

Comment: Please include your attempt in the body of the question, and describe exactly what the result was. Saying "didn't work" doesn't help us.

Comment: WARNING: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern development framework like Laravel comes with a robust authentication system built-in.

Comment: @JoeAlvini You're asking him to use a framework instead of learning first the language? wow.

Comment: Dude being new  to this my above answer is the best advice anyone could ever give. I just wished I wasn't so hard headed and I listened when a seasoned member on here said this to me. It would've saved me a great deal of work and a lot of headaches.

Comment: @César Escudero ... Bad habits are bad habits whether from the start or picking them up along the way. Would you call the above code learning the language or picking up a ton of bad habits?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct syntax for mysql delete is;-

```
DELETE FROM table_name WHERE column = value;
```

in your case it will be

```
DELETE FROM `a_codes` WHERE `username` = "insert the username here"
```

or

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("DELETE FROM a_codes WHERE username = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $username);
$stmt->execute();
```